# can I connect 120/240 split phase washer If I just have 3 phase 220v?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I want to install washer the washer connection box has 4 wires L1,L2,N,and GND (split phase) but unfortunately I do not have split phase power source I have 3 phase 220v instead, the question is can I use 2 phases to connect L1 and L2 ?  is this solution applicable and will not cause any damage to the machine?

Comment: Where in the world are you, and is your 240V 3ph a delta or a wye arrangement?

Comment: This is a bad idea. You'll be putting 220V where your washer is expecting 120V (Line-to-Neutral) and 380V where your washer is expecting 240V (Line-to-Line).

Comment: @brhans We don't know what his 3 phase service is. We don't know where in the world he is located. And we also don't know what kind of washer it is either. Though, I'm guessing this is a commercial dryer since it has a junction box.

Comment: @MisterTea - yes - when I see "3-phase 220V" I just automatically jump to the 220/380 European system I'm used to. Way too many different options here in North America ...

Comment: @brhans There are lots of voltage variations all over. In Europe and elsewhere, there is 220-380, 230-400 (nominal standard) and 240-416. Rumor has it there used to be 240V delta systems in Norway. Australia and I also think NZ stuck with 240-416. In the USA we have and had a few different systems including 220V split phase. To complicate things, people tend to say 220 or even 240 when referring to either split phase or open wye setup in the 208-240V range. It's a generic term so to speak.

Comment: I have 3 phase 220v (Line to Line) WYE arrangement I am in Saudia Arabia , the washer is for medical instrument the manufacturer is GETINGE the techincal data for the washer is in the below link http://www.getinge.com/files/us-hc/product-documents/cleaning-and-disinfection/pretreatment-and-cleaningarea/2460rd/productspecification/hc-wsds-ps-2460rinserdryer-1107-en-us.pdf

Answer (score 1):

As threephaseEel is pointing out it depends on the configuration. I would hope it is a Wye all 3 phases have the same voltage to ground but with a delta the the B phase is "wild" or 2x the other 2 that's when things go boom. If your voltage is 220 the line to neutral value should be 127V depending on the washer's wiring this may work if code legal in your area and the washer requires 120V.
Almost all lighting in industrial plants are from Wye connected transformers using 1 leg, for example : 480V 3 phase 1 leg to neutral is 277 or 480/1.732. The neutral connection back at the transformer is connected to the ground.  A more common example in light industrial facilities Wye connected also would be 208/120 3 phase the line to neutral here is only 120V  (208/1.732).
In my early days the low voltage 3 phase was 230V this is a bit high for a single leg to ground on a 120V but it was used back then there was not as much digital electronic gear I believe this is the reason 208 3 phase has become the standard now. Verifying the actual voltage and connection type is very important. With all 3 legs to ground measuring the same value it is a Wye connection. Measuring the legs to ground and 1 leg (usually the B phase) is 2X the voltage is a Delta you cannot use the B leg or "wild" leg, but the A & C leg can be used for 120.

Comment: I have WYE Connection transformer 220v Line to Line 127v Line to GND

Comment: I have WYE Connection transformer (220v Line to Line) (127v Line to GND) the machine electricity tag mentions that the machine is 1 phase 220 v (split phase) this means I have L1,L2,N,GND.  the problem is we do not have split phase power in Saudia Arabia I just have 220v Line to Line my Idea is to use two phases coming from the transformer output instead of split phase because simply we dont have it the voltage will be almost the same

Comment: Phase lag in the split phase 180 degrees/phase lag between two phases coming out from the transformer is 120 degree would this affect on the machine ?

Comment: The instructions show this will run on single phase 208 60 hz, 220 & 240 50 or 60 hz. Being in the U.S. I was focusing on 120V.  to make your washer work you should be able to connect 2 legs of the 3 phase to L1 & L2 this is how we run a single phase motor 240V on a 230 3 phase service. you will also need the neutral so if any of the solenoids are 120V they will work and last the equipment ground to the frame.

Comment: If you have a 127-230 wye, then you can in fact connect the dryer to your mains as Ed noted. The thing is, you don't say whether you have a neutral when a wye should indeed supply one unless SA doesn't use the neutral and instead treats it like a three wire 220V three phase system with just a ground. If this is the case and you only have a ground, the ground can serve as the neutral point. The extra 7 volts shouldn't be too great a burden on the internals. Ensure the ground is solid otherwise you will have a few problems.

Comment: regarding the neutral availability actually the hospital has 380 v (line to line) in addition to the neutral but I bought a transformer converts from 380 v to 220 v (Line-Line) so I will use the neutral coming from the hospital and I will use the lines coming from the transformer (220 v L-L)